# What is the Difference between ConditionPathExists= and ConditionPathExists=| in systemd?

Tags: linux, redhat, systemd

I need check a file not exist before i start my service in Systemd. I see two case in [Unit]:

```
ConditionPathExists=!/tmp/abc
```

and

```
ConditionPathExists=|!/tmp/abc
```

are they the same? Can anybody help me explain if they are different?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Sometime you specify multiple files like:

```
ConditionPathExists=!/tmp/abc
ConditionPathExists=!/tmp/abe
```

Now if any of the condition isn't satisfied, it doesn't start service. It's like and operations.

Now if you use:

```
ConditionPathExists=|!/tmp/abc
ConditionPathExists=|!/tmp/abe
```

If any of these conditions is satisfied, it will run the service.

> Condition checks can be prefixed with a pipe symbol (|) in which case
>   a condition becomes a triggering condition. If at least one triggering
>   condition is defined for a unit, then the unit will be executed if at
>   least one of the triggering conditions apply and all of the
>   non-triggering conditions

It's like OR operations

Comment: Thanks you very much :)

Comment: +1 A blessing and a pain with systemd is the little very useful details can be hidden in the volume of manual pages.  Thanks for highlighting this @khrm